# BeautifulSoup confused

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on script in python with BeautifulSoup to find some data from html. I got a stacked and so much confused, my brain stopped working, I don't have any idea how to scrape full address of these elements:

```
<li class="spacer">
<span>Location:</span> 
<br>Some Sample Street<br>
Abbeville, AL 00000
</li>
```

I have tried something like `location = info.find('li', 'spacer').text`
but still I got only string "Location: " . Tried with many parents - child relations but still can't figure out how to scrape this one..

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Works for me on this sample HTML. Are you sure you have the full address in the actual HTML you are working with?

Comment: This is same as my HTML part, for me only prints "Location: "

Comment: @Ukii, add a link to the site, what you have posted `.find('li', 'spacer').text` would get so obviously there is more to the issue than you have shown us.

Comment: @Ukii - Is your problem solved ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
locations = info.find_all('span',Class_="spacer")
for location in locations:
    print (location.text)
```

Comment: Even if I try 
locations = soup.find_all('span',Class_="spacer")
for location in locations:
    print (location.text)
it won't print anything

Comment: I don't need <span>Location:</span> I said that I am getting that always, but I need those two elements down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nextSibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#nextSibling%20and%20previousSibling) to navigate to the next elements inside the `li` and after the `span`

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html_text= """
<li class="spacer">
<span>Location:</span> 
<br>Some Sample Street<br>
Abbeville, AL 00000
</li>
"""
location_address = ""

html_souped = Soup(html_text, 'html.parser')

# get the next sibling after the span:
siblings = html_souped.find('li', {'class': 'spacer'}).find('span').nextSibling

# iterate until the end of the li element: 
while siblings.nextSibling is not None:
    # add the text to the location:
    location_address += siblings.nextSibling.text
    siblings = siblings.nextSibling

# print the stripped location:
print('location: ' + location_address.strip())
```

This will work perfectly for all your list if the list has the same format as your given example.